# How to split a file using a numeric suffix

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command

I'm using the following command to split a file.  It should split every 50,000 lines and use a 4-digit numeric suffix.  The file is about 140 million lines.

```
split -d -l -n 4 50000 domains.xml domains_
```

But when I run that I am getting this error:

```
split: -n: invalid number of lines
Try `split --help' for more information.
```

What's the correct command for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use `awk`. It gives you finer control over your output files and filenames. It should be just ask quick too. Here's how to split a 100 line file into 20 line blocks:

```
awk 'NR%20==1 { file = FILENAME "_" sprintf("%04d", NR+19) } { print > file }' domains.xml
```

This should create some files like:

```
file_0020
file_0040
file_0060
file_0080
file_0100
```

Adjust accordingly. HTH.

Answer (score 85):

Since the primary help from GNU `split` says:

```
Usage: /usr/gnu/bin/split [OPTION]... [INPUT [PREFIX]]
Output fixed-size pieces of INPUT to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default
size is 1000 lines, and default PREFIX is 'x'.  With no INPUT, or when INPUT
is -, read standard input.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -a, --suffix-length=N   generate suffixes of length N (default 2)
      --additional-suffix=SUFFIX  append an additional SUFFIX to file names.
  -b, --bytes=SIZE        put SIZE bytes per output file
  -C, --line-bytes=SIZE   put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file
  -d, --numeric-suffixes[=FROM]  use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic.
                                   FROM changes the start value (default 0).
  -e, --elide-empty-files  do not generate empty output files with '-n'
      --filter=COMMAND    write to shell COMMAND; file name is $FILE
  -l, --lines=NUMBER      put NUMBER lines per output file
  -n, --number=CHUNKS     generate CHUNKS output files.  See below
  -u, --unbuffered        immediately copy input to output with '-n r/...'
      --verbose           print a diagnostic just before each
                            output file is opened
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

It looks to me like you need to reorganize your options a bit:

```
split -a 4 -d -l 50000 domains.xml domains_
```

Comment: This should be the right answer to the problem. The previous one is an alternative answer but this solve the issue using the same command

Comment: FYI, this doesn't work on macOS since mac's built-in `split` command doesn't come with `-d` option (and no equivalent option with different name)

Comment: On MacOS, this command is called `gsplit` (or you need to install it, because the regular `split` that comes with MacOS doesn't come with these options). However, with `gsplit` you can't specify a number after the -d option (always starts counting from 0)

Comment: @blitter — I'm curious: which directory is `gsplit` installed in on your MacOS machine?  I don't have `gsplit` on either 10.14.6 Mojave (don't ask) or 10.15.5 Catalina.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I found it twice: 
`/usr/local/bin/gsplit
/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.25/bin/gsplit`
I probably installed it myself at some point -- unlikely that MacOS ships with GNU software. I just wanted to point out that that alternative exists on MacOS, where the normal `split` is outdated compared to `gsplit`. The command to search your whole hard disk for it is: `find / -name gsplit`

Answer (score 15):

(From manpage, GNU coreutils 8.21)
What you need seems to be -a/--suffix-length=N (generate suffixes of length N (default 2)), not -n/--number=CHUNKS (generate CHUNKS output files)

```
split -d -l 50000 -a 4 domains.xml domains_
```

and you should get: domains_0000, domains_0001...

Answer (score 5):

Although you haven't asked for it but I suppose you'd want a proper extension to the resultant files (let us say xml) :

```sh
split -d -l 50000 -a 4 --additional-suffix=.xml domains.xml domains_
```

The `--additional-suffix=.xml` will make file names of type `domains_0000.xml`, `domains_1453.xml` etc.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this helps you, but if you add a 1 to your filename prefix i.e. `outfile1` you will end up with:

```
outfile101
outfile102
outfile103
```

I understand this might not be what you are looking for, but various programs do not parse leading zeros in job arrays and such, no matter if computer scientists "always count from zero". At least this way you can parse your files with a wider range of programs.